# Attach the DotTrace Performance profiler with Visual Studio Load Testing

Tags: asp.net, memory, dottrace

Is there, Any way I can attach the DotTrace performance profiler with Visual studio Load testing project. I am checking the load testing of the ASP.NET Web Application. I am trying to create stress test and trying to do more analysis. I am just curious that is there any way there we can attach DotTrace performance profiler with the Visual Studio Load test and check the details of the Load test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to profile your ASP.NET web application when the load test is running, right? In this case, you can just attach to the corresponding process (for example, to w3wp.exe process if your project is hosted on IIS) and profile it when the load test is running. See this page for details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profile_Running_Process.html

Answer (score 1):

This answer just incase if you dont have production or TEST environment access to attach the process and all. You can connect to the same TEST DB or Dev DB when load testing is happening from the local environment then attach the process of the IIS running app and check the dotTrace analysis.